# Why is there still a white background even though a transparent png image is used?

Tags: rendering, texturing, transparency

I have a very simple node set up as below for a leaf texture which is a transparent backgrounded png file. When I use the transparent shader with alpha node, I still get the white backround appearing as below, I can't figure out what's the problem here, please help.

Render view

[image]

nodes

[image]

PNG [file](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/89485)

Blender [file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36582)

thanks a lot

Ps. I went through questions already asked here for this subject, they didn't solve my problem, even though it's a very simple node set-up - sorry if it's a duplicate which I haven't seen yet

Answer (score 5):

Open up the *Node Editor*, select the image texture node, then open the *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd> and enable **Use Alpha**.

[image: enable alpha]

Comment: Hi Chis, welcome to blender.se :) For your next answers, see: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

I opened your file, everything is OK, even in render view. In your photo it seems that the leaf is projecting a shadow on an object just underneath; is there a duplicate? I hope it can be helpful[image]

Comment: it's only one leaf, but for some reason png files transparent parts didn't recognised by blender, then i open my png file and saved it as png again , it worked this time, i don't know how it didn't in the first place..thanks for the answer btw

Comment: @ideorium I have had the same issue, IDK if it is a bug or what